# Where can I get the source code of String class in Java

Tags: java, string

I want to modify the replace() method of String class. But I can't find the code for it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not google "replace() in java" and reed the links you get?

Comment: "I want to modify the replace() method of String class" that looks like bad idea. Is it possible that your question is [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: When you download the jdk you can get the source code which is in src.zip.


You're probably aware, but String is a final class so you can't extend or override methods.

Comment: I just needed the code for replace() function to be able to work on a problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html this is Java doc URL.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html you can find source code here...

Answer (score 2):

The source code is available in the [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.org/) project.

Here is the link to the source of the `String` class: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java